# Getting two rows "in scope" for a PostgreSQL function call: cross join?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, user-defined-functions

I have a user-defined function `similarity()` that compares two users and returns a score.  Right now, the calling query looks like:

```
SELECT similarity(user1, user2)
FROM (
  SELECT users.id
  FROM users AS user1
  WHERE users.id = 123
)
CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT users.id
  FROM users AS user2
  WHERE users.id = 456
);
```

This feels messy.  Is there a better way to set up the two users for the function call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one from each table (seems likely that `id` is a PK) then

```
SELECT similarity((SELECT a FROM users a WHERE a.id=123), 
   (SELECT b FROM users b WHERE b.id=456));
```

Comment: Thanks - that's what I was missing (I can do subqueries in the SELECT clause instead of the FROM clause).

Answer (score 1):

Simplified form that does exactly the same:

```
SELECT similarity(a, b)
FROM   users a, users b
WHERE  a.id = 123
AND    b.id = 456;
```

Comment: I wasn't clear; the subqueries are necessary in the actual query.

Comment: @JayLevitt You can insert subqueries in place of the tables. Be advised that Andrews variant yields **different** results if one of the two tuples does not exist. That's why I chose this form.